# Extract multiple zip files from text list into their own folders with error log

Tags: command-line, archive, unzip

I wish to unzip ZIP files from a text list, each one into its own folder and output the errors into a log file.

The list looks like this:

```
0001.zip
0002.zip
```

I know i can use the following command but I just don't know how
to accomplish the above.

```
find -name '*.zip' -exec sh -c 'unzip -d "${1%.*}" "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do these files exist in the directory where you ran the command from?

Comment: Yes, the files exist.

Answer (score 7):

Since you already have the extraction command `sh -c 'unzip -d "${1%.*}" "$1"'`, you can use `xargs` to convert input files to arguments:

```
xargs -a list-of-files -L1 sh -c 'unzip -d "${1%.*}" "$1"' _
```

The `{}` is not needed since `xargs` by default appends the input to argument list. The `-L1` makes it use one line of input as an argument.

Then just redirect the output to a file:

```
xargs -a list-of-files -L1 sh -c 'unzip -d "${1%.*}" "$1"' _ &> zip.log
```

Or just the errors:

```
xargs -a list-of-files -L1 sh -c 'unzip -d "${1%.*}" "$1"' _ 2> zip.log
```

Comment: Thank you @muru, i am getting an error "unzip: cannot find or open file * ". What needs to be the format of the list?

Comment: List of files, one per line. If there are empty lines, use the `-r` option with xargs.

Comment: I am getting an error that the unzip cannot find or open the file, please advise.

Comment: Edit your question to show this list of files.

Comment: Hi @muru, when i am adding echo before the unzip command i get the following output: unzip -d 0001 0001.zip, when i am trying to run the command the output in the log is: .ZIP.or 0001.zipind or open 0001.zip, please advise.

Answer (score 6):

If we presume you have a text list of zip files like:

```
zipfile1.zip
another_archive.zip
...
```

then you can do

```sh
cat ziplist.txt | while read zipfile; do
    zipdir="$(basename "$zipfile").d"

    (
        mkdir "$zipdir"
        cd "$zipdir"
        echo "Extracting $PWD/../$zipfile"
        unzip "../$zipfile" 2>&1 > "../$zipfile.log"
    )
done
```

This will create a directory, unzip the zip file into it, whilst writing everything out to a log file in the same directory as the zip file itself.

Comment: You probably should do a `cd -` to return to the original directory (or run the `cd ...; unzip` in a subshell.

Comment: thank you @taifwa, i am getting an error when trying to run the script: .ZIP.or ../0001.zip or open ../0001.zip, please advise.

Comment: check the zip file actually exists at the path specified.

Comment: i am running it from the path of the ZIP files, i will try to figure out what is wrong.